# Simple put request Angular-->Java/spring not working

Tags: java, angular, spring, post, put

I have an objects in java backend that i want to change status property on:

```
@Entity 
public class Employee { 
    @Id @GeneratedValue long id; 
    private  String name; 
    private  String status;
```

}

I want to set the property status to "Checked" for a targeted object chosen with id with this putmapping:

```
@PutMapping("/api/users/id") 
public Employee changeStatus(@RequestParam Long id) 
{ 
       Employee newEmployee = userRepository.getById(id); 
       newEmployee.setStatus("Checked"); 
       return userRepository.save(newEmployee); 
}
```

I want to do it from my frontend through :

```
public changeStatus(id: number): Observable<any> 
{ 
    return this.http.put<any>(${this.apiServerUrl}/users/id, id) 
}
```

Nothing happens in backend, no errors or anything shows up. What am i missing? I suspect i do something wrong in the frontend call, but i cant figure it out.

Backend-frontend connections seems to work because i can get all data from my backend and see it in frontend with theese two endpoints

Backend:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/users") public List<Employee> getUsers() 
{ 
     return (List<Employee>) userRepository.findAll(); 
}
```

Frontend:

```
public getUsers(): Observable<any>
{ 
    return this.http.get<any>(${this.apiServerUrl}/users) 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you subscribing to this call on the FE ? the angular HttpClient returns an `Observable`, if you are not subscribing, i.e. if you are not doing something like this:

```js
getUsers().subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('whatever');
})
```

The http request will never be send, that's how observable works, they only get "executed" when someone is "listening"

Comment: Yes i am doing a subscribe when i call the getUsers()! Getting the users works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how you try to pass `id` as pathVariable your endpoint should also accept it as such. For that refactor your endpoint. Frontend looks fine.

```java
@PutMapping("/api/users/{id}")
public Employee changeStatus(@PathVariable Long id) 
{ 
       Employee newEmployee = userRepository.getById(id); 
       newEmployee.setStatus("Checked"); 
       return userRepository.save(newEmployee); 
}
```

Remove one extra `id` from url.

```js
public changeStatus(id: number): Observable<any> 
{ 
    const url = this.apiServerUrl + /users/ + id;
    return this.http.put<any>(url);
}
```

Otherwise try to get rid of `any` types and use strong typing - that's the benefit TypeScript gives us.

Comment: When i try to change the frontend changeStatus like you suggested i get this error:
Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
http.d.ts(2934, 25): An argument for 'body' was not provided.  I suppose it expects a body since its a put call?